# Trying to pass a string from an activity to a fragment when login is successful (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, bundle

I'm developing an app where I made a login and register with firebase. I'm trying to pass a string from an activity to a fragment and The function that sends the strings gets called when the login or the register is successful. Then the string passed to the fragment is shown in a textView, but that doesn't happen. This is the Register class when the function is created. Thanks in advance!

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*

class Register : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
        setup()
    }
    private fun setup(){
        registerBtn.setOnClickListener{
            if(emailEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.text.toString(),
                    passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener{
                        if(it.isSuccessful){
                            //If email doesn't exists send empty string(shouldn't happen,
                            //already controlled with createUserWithEmailAndPassword.isSuccesful
                            passUserData()
                            showMainMenu()
                        }else{
                            showAlert()
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener{
            if(emailEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.text.toString(),
                    passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        //If email doesn't exists send empty string(shouldn't happen,
                        //already controlled with createUserWithEmailAndPassword.isSuccesful
                        passUserData()
                        showMainMenu()
                    }else{
                        showAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun showAlert(){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Error")
        builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error al intentar autenticar el usuario")
        builder.setPositiveButton("Acceptar", null)
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun showMainMenu(){
        val goMainMenu = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(goMainMenu)
    }
    private fun passUserData(){
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("sayhi", "Hello")
        val transact = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val myFrag = FourthFragment()
        myFrag.arguments = bundle
        transact.commit()
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment (as you can see I tried to put the same code in both methods to see if it worked):

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView


enum class ProviderType{
    BASIC
}
class FourthFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (arguments != null){
            val sayHello = requireArguments().getString("sayhi")
            val showtext : TextView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.emailShow)
            showtext.text = "$sayHello"
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fourth, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (arguments != null){
            val sayHello = requireArguments().getString("sayhi")
            val showtext : TextView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.emailShow)
            showtext.text = "$sayHello"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing that you need is to pass some data from activity to fragment, right?

Comment: Yes, and showing it on a textView. Later I will use this to get the user email, but that will be easier if I know how to pass the string to the fragment. But the code doesn't show any errors and I don't know what else to try. If you need any more code to help me out just say it!

Comment: Where is passUserData() called from?

Comment: Instead of describing what your code looks like, please add it to your question.